# Bootstrap 3. Три колонки одинаковой высоты с изображениями thumbnail

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите пожалуйста сделать три колонки одинаковой высоты через bootstrap, причём, в первой и третьей колонке по два элемента(изображения: (375x410 и 375х200) ), а во второй(центральной) колонке -- три элемента (370х200).
Возможно нужно играться с отступами между элементами?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://peliculacompletaenespañollatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Yo-Vi-Al-Diablo-Pelicula-Completa-en-Espa%C3%B1ol-Latino-375x410.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://napolimonitor.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/al-centro-del-tifone.-incontro-con-chiara-guidi-img-375x200.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://publishersconvention.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Seoul-370x200.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://publishersconvention.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Seoul-370x200.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://publishersconvention.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Seoul-370x200.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://napolimonitor.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/al-centro-del-tifone.-incontro-con-chiara-guidi-img-375x200.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://peliculacompletaenespañollatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Yo-Vi-Al-Diablo-Pelicula-Completa-en-Espa%C3%B1ol-Latino-375x410.jpg" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: Учитесь верстать без бутстрапа и у вас все получится.

Comment: Мне надо сверстать бутстрапом, если бы мне надо было верстать без бутстрапа, я бы не задавал этот вопрос. Просто в бутстрапе я новичёк, а гугл плохо помогает, вот и спрашиваю у сообщества.

Comment: Если бы вы умели верстать без бутстрапа, то не задавали бы такой вопрос.

Comment: мне надо именно через бутстрап, если вы не знаете как это сделать то незачем на stackoverflow писать поучения, этот сайт предназначен не для этого.

Comment: Вам тогда на фриланс надо заказ делать, раз с бутстрапом и без сверстать не можете :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    ....
```

Comment: ответ взят отсюда http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/